# useEffect promise throwing Typescript errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-effect

`useEffect(login, [])`

Where login returns a promise.
I don't need the return, I just want it to fire.

Gives the following Typescript errors:

```
Argument of type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
  Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor'.t
```

Yet, this does not throw errors:

```
useEffect(() => {
    login()
  }, [])
```

Why does the first throw TS errors?

Comment: Because `login` returns `Promise<void>`, not `void` or `Destructor`

Comment: Besides the arrow function, I now also use react-use useAsync just for that...

Answer (score 2):

It is technically different returns, while your login returns a promise, `useEffect` does expect the `EffectCallback` to be met, which is basically to return a function that is called once the component is being unmounted or `void` (nothing).

- [See more about useEffect here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect).

To give a more step-by-step type of answer:

- `useEffect` accepts a function that is called `EffectCallback` in typescript terms.
- That `EffectCallback` cannot by anything else than a plain function.
- It should return `void` (nothing) or `Destructor` which is a plain function called once the component is being unmounted.